# End of Mining intention

Tags: blockchain, block, mining-theory, bitcoinj

If every block generated all 10 Minutes to validate a transaction, and the last bitcoin will generated in 2140. And there is no limitation of blocks.. Whats after 2140, because all miner have no intention to validate any transaction. How will Bitcoin generate the other blocks?

Comment: "*because all miner have no intention to validate any transaction*" Where did you get that from?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is known that Miner offers the p2p Network their computing power and receive bitcoins. And a validation of a transaction is only generated by a generated block.

Comment: That's correct. But what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz we have a limit of bitcoins, there will be 21 millions in 2140. So if every bitcoin is in posession in this specific year there no miner become any bitcoin from mining.

Comment: That's not true. They'll still get to keep the transaction fees for transactions in the blocks they mine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz where did you get this information? But thank you this wasnt passed in my mind.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees